# Swift sort array of objects based on boolean value

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift

I'm looking for a way to sort a Swift array based on a Boolean value.

I've got it working using a cast to NSArray:

```
var boolSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "selected", ascending: false)
var array = NSArray(array: results)
return array.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([boolSort]) as! [VDLProfile]
```

But I'm looking for the Swift variant, any ideas?

**Update**
Thanks to Arkku, I've managed to fix this using the following code:

```
return results.sorted({ (leftProfile, rightProfile) -> Bool in
    return leftProfile.selected == true && rightProfile.selected != true
})
```

Comment: re. update in the question, comparing booleans with `true` is unnecessary clutter, and it would be better Swift style to omit the `()` around the closure (as is permitted when the closure is the last argument).

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Swift's arrays can be sorted in place with `sort` or to a new array with `sorted`. The single parameter of either function is a closure taking two elements and returning `true` if and only if the first is ordered before the second. The shortest way to use the closure's parameters is by referring to them as `$0` and `$1`.

For example (to sort the true booleans first):

```
// In-place:
array.sort { $0.selected && !$1.selected }

// To a new array:
array.sorted { $0.selected && !$1.selected }
```

(edit: Updated for Swift 3, 4 and 5, previously `sort` was `sortInPlace` and `sorted` was `sort`.)

Comment: Thanks, using your answer I've managed to fix this in Swift. I've updated my question with the answer.

Comment: Please note that in Swift 3.0 .sort is used

Answer (score 4):

**New (for Swift 1.2)**

```
return results.sort { $0.selected && !$1.selected }
```

**Old (for Swift 1.0)**

Assuming `results` is of type `[VDLProfile]` and VDLProfile has a `Bool` member `selected`:

```
return results.sorted { $0.selected < $1.selected }
```

See documentation for [sorted](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Algorithms.html)

Comment: This gave me an error: Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type.

Answer (score 0):

Swift’s standard library provides a function called sorted, which sorts an array of values of a known type, based on the output of a sorting closure that you provide

```
reversed = sorted(array) { $0 > $1 }
```

`reversed` will be a new array which will be sorted according to the condition given in the closure.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - OP needs to sort by boolean values which cannot be compared using > or <. (also the first sentence is copied word for word from the Swift book)