# Sort Bool Array

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3, boolean

I have an array of Booleans that I will like to sort:

```
var array = [true,false,true,false]
```

im not sure how to use the sorted method:

```
playersArray.sorted(by: (Bool, Bool) -> Bool)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781031/swift-sort-array-of-objects-based-on-boolean-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1: Use `sorted` with a minimal closure**

If you are going to use `sorted`, and you want the `true`s to be first, it can just be written as:

```
let sorted = array.sorted { $0 && !$1 }
```

**Explanation**

The closure you provide to `sorted` takes 2 `Bool` and returns a `Bool`.  Based on the closure you provided, here is a table that maps the input of 2 `Bool` to the desired output:

```
input            desired answer
-------------    --------------
false < true     false
true  < false    true
false < false    false
true  < true     false
```

Since you want `true` to appear first in your array then `true < false` and `false > true`.

So, you want to return `true` when the first input is true and the second input is false.  This can be written simply as `{ $0 && !$1 }`.

---

**Method 2:  Radix Sort**

Since there are only 2 values, it would be more efficient to just count one of them and then create an array that has the right number of `true`s and `false`s.  This would run in linear time O(n) which is faster than sorting for large arrays.

```
let trueCount = array.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1 ? 1 : 0) }
let sorted = Array(repeating: true, count: trueCount) +
             Array(repeating: false, count: array.count - trueCount)
```

---

**Performance Comparisons**

Here is a comparison of the 3 methods on a `10,000` element array running on a 2.4GHz i5 MacBook Pro.  This was compiled in release mode:

```
sorting function          time for 100 runs (seconds)
----------------          --------------
Your answer               0.44872701
Method 1                  0.18970698
Method 2                  0.00229198
```

The *radix sort method* is approximately `82` times faster.

Comment: Thank you, awesome explanation!

Answer (score 0):

got it!

```
array.sorted {$0.description > $1.description}
```

Comment: This will convert each of the bools to strings. Not recommended.