# How to find unique value from Array of object in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have declared an `Array` like :

```
  var sessionsToDisplayTemp : [SessionData] = []
```

The value of `sessionsToDisplayTemp` is:

```
[<SessionData: 0x600001c16a30> (entity: SessionData; id: 0x8b2a8ba144e57f29 <x-coredata://0A752C13-D33E-4AE2-BE3E-7B856C0EE8D9/SessionData/p3> ; data: {

    startTime = "14:30";
    switchInGroup = FALSE;

}), <SessionData: 0x600001c16a80> (entity: SessionData; id: 0x8b2a8ba144f97f29 <x-coredata://0A752C13-D33E-4AE2-BE3E-7B856C0EE8D9/SessionData/p4> ; data: {

    startTime = "13:30";
    switchInGroup = TRUE;

}), <SessionData: 0x600001c16cb0> (entity: SessionData; id: 0x8b2a8ba144fd7f29 <x-coredata://0A752C13-D33E-4AE2-BE3E-7B856C0EE8D9/SessionData/p5> ; data: {
        startTime = "13:30";
    switchInGroup = FALSE;

})]
```

My problem is I have to check the Start time, if the start time will be same then have to hide from this array and this array should be in the order of Start Time. I mean the final array should be :

```
[<SessionData: 0x600001c16a30> (entity: SessionData; id: 0x8b2a8ba144e57f29 <x-coredata://0A752C13-D33E-4AE2-BE3E-7B856C0EE8D9/SessionData/p3> ; data: {

        startTime = "13:30";
        switchInGroup = TRUE;

    }), <SessionData: 0x600001c16a80> (entity: SessionData; id: 0x8b2a8ba144f97f29 <x-coredata://0A752C13-D33E-4AE2-BE3E-7B856C0EE8D9/SessionData/p4> ; data: {

        startTime = "14:30";
        switchInGroup = FALSE;

    })]
```

I have done the ascending part based on Start time using :

```
sessionsToDisplayTemp.sort(by: { $0.startTime?.compare(($1.startTime)!) == .orderedAscending })
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: sessionsToDisplayTemp.sort(by: { $0.startTime?.compare(($1.startTime)!) == .orderedAscending })

Comment: How can I apply both filters?

Comment: you can use `set` for your concept , see this for e.g : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790228/remove-duplicates-from-array-of-dictionaries-swift-3

Comment: Still same issue @Anbu.Karthik, Can you help me. The problem is I can set the order Start Time wise, but duplicate Start time value is not removing,

Comment: try this also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381075/swift-3-0-remove-duplicates-in-array-of-dictionaries?rq=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188518/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create an array, `out`, that is sorted and without duplicates

```
var out = [SessionData]()
for data in sessionsToDisplayTemp.sorted(by: { $0.startTime < $1.startTime}) {
    if out.isEmpty {
        out.append(data)
    } else if let last = out.last, last.startTime != data.startTime {
        out.append(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Joakim, Thank you for your response, I am getting error: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'String?' operands. My startTime is String here..

Comment: I am using : @NSManaged public var startTime: String?

Comment: @AnandGautam then I need to change the sorting part but why is startTime optional?

Comment: sessionsToDisplayTemp.sort(by: { $0.startTime?.compare(($1.startTime)!) == .orderedAscending })

                var out = [SessionData]()
                for data in sessionsToDisplayTemp{
                    if out.isEmpty {
                        out.append(data)
                    } else if let last = out.last, last.startTime != data.startTime {
                        out.append(data)
                    }
                }

Comment: Hi@Joakim, you there? I have a doubt here.

Comment: @AnandGautam what is your issue?

Comment: The problem is I need to again sort the array based on switchInGroup Boolean. All true values should come first. Please guide me

Comment: sorted(by:) or sort(by:) takes a closure and in that closure you can define your own sorting algorithm there. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781031/swift-sort-array-of-objects-based-on-boolean-value)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188522/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: @AnandGautam I added a link

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array, where you would append only the `SessionData` objects with unique `startTime`. 
To make it easy, you can use `Set` as mentioned by @Anbu.Karthik in the comments.

As a simulation of your `SessionData`I use a Tuple

```
var sessionToDisplay : [(startTime: String, switchInGroup: Bool)] = [
  (startTime: "14:30", switchInGroup: false),
  (startTime: "13:30", switchInGroup: true),
  (startTime: "13:30", switchInGroup: false),
];
```

Then the code would be like this:

```
var uniqueTimes = Set<String>();
var newArr : [(startTime: String, switchInGroup: Bool)] = [];

//Add only the objects with unique startTime (first occurrence in original array)
for (st, sig) in sessionToDisplay{
  if(uniqueTimes.insert(st).inserted){
    newArr.append((st, sig));
  }
}

//Sort as you need
newArr.sort(by: { $0.startTime.compare(($1.startTime)) == .orderedAscending });
```